# Match a series number with a certain name before

Tags: python, regex

I need to match a number with several points in the middle after the word `studies` or `studiesUID` and before the next word.

Here an example:

```
studies: ['1.2.840.113619.2.248.116524556585.23765.1290700521734.13', '1.2.840.113619.2.248.116524556585.23765.1290700523548.1000'] as const,
seriesUID: '1.2.840.113619.2.65.4.2123217250.13335.1164292845.4',
```

should only get me:

```
1.2.840.113619.2.248.116524556585.23765.1290700521734.13
1.2.840.113619.2.248.116524556585.23765.1290700523548.1000
```

and not the number after `seriesUID`

I already succeeded to match the number with `r'\d+[\.\d+]'`.
I tried matching the first word with `r'(studies|studyUID)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*\d+[\.\d+]+'` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python `re` it would be easier to first match the pattern, and then from that match extract the numbers.

If you want a bit more accurate pattern to match the numbers not allowing consecutive dots, then instead of `\d[\d.]*` you can use `\d+(?:\.\d+)*`

```
import re

s = ("studies: ['1.2.840.113619.2.248.116524556585.23765.1290700521734.13', '1.2.840.113619.2.248.116524556585.23765.1290700523548.1000'] as const,\n"
            "seriesUID: '1.2.840.113619.2.65.4.2123217250.13335.1164292845.4',")
pattern = r"\b(?:studies|studyUID):\s+\['\d[\d.]*'(?:,\s*'\d[\d.]*)*']"
match = re.search(pattern, s)
if match:
    print(re.findall(r"\d[\d.]*", match.group()))
```

Output

```
[
  '1.2.840.113619.2.248.116524556585.23765.1290700521734.13', 
  '1.2.840.113619.2.248.116524556585.23765.1290700523548.1000'
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Indeed not consecutive points is better. I did a minor change because I wanted to allow wither `studies: [<my series numbers>]` and also `studies: <one series number>` . For that I matched like this: `r"\b(?:studies|studyUID):[^a-zA-Z0-9]*'\d[\d.]*'(?:,\s*'\d[\d.]*)*"`